# create SPF record for series of IPs

Tags: email, dns, spf

I have 45 IPs, `180.72.100.80` to `180.72.100.124`
How can I specify them in one SPF record?
I've tried `v=spf1 +mx +a +ip4:180.72.100.80/180.72.100.124 -all`
but this results in `spf=permerror` (seen from show Original section in gmail)
I've searched over and found entries suggesting `180.72.100.80/24` or some other number but couldn't get how this notation works or how to build this type of notation with my IPs

Comment: It doesn't deserve to be down-voted, I up-voted it for you. Here's another handy [IP to CIDR Tool](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/ipcidr/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a little confused over you IP-range as I thought that addresses was normally assigned in "whole" networks (able to match with a subnet- or network-mask)

But to get the 45 addresses into the SPF (without having to list them all), you need to convert the addresses to CIDR (x.x.x.x/n). There are several online tools that can help you with that (e.g. http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr). Your IP-range give the following CIDR records:

```
180.72.100.80/28
180.72.100.96/28
180.72.100.112/29
180.72.100.120/30
180.72.100.124/32
```

So the complete SPF record should look like this (you don't need the + qualifier since it's the default):

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:180.72.100.80/28 ip4:180.72.100.96/28 ip4:180.72.100.112/29 ip4:180.72.100.120/30 ip4:180.72.100.124/32 -all
```

Comment: I recommend putting the `ip4` clauses first (before `a` and `mx`) as it saves receivers from doing DNS lookups